# Is it possible to analyze in SONAR a Groovy project with FindBug Quality profiles (found in FindBugs plugin)?

Tags: groovy, sonarqube, findbugs

I installed Sonar, and Groovy and FindBugs plugins. After start up, the 3 findbugs profiles appear only with the Java langage. The Groovy langage remains only with the default choice : sonar way.

Versions used: 
SonarQube 5.2
SonarRunner 2.4
Sonar Groovy plugin 1.3.1
Sonar findbugs plugin 3.3

If not possible, do someone know another plugin to do the job for Groovy?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, FindBugs is for Java only. Since Groovy compiles to Java Bytecode, it would be possible to run FindBugs on your Groovy stuff as a Java analysis. The results would not be very helpful, though.

In my opinion, you will have to rely on the rules supplied by the SonarQube Groovy Plugin, which offers 349 rules (as of version 1.3.1 of the plugin). They are mostly based on [Codenarc](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/).

The "Sonar Way" profile is just a suggestion by the SonarQube team with 57 selected rules. You can create your own profile to use all the others.